# GCP cloud run custom domain: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, gcp-load-balancer

I have set up a cloud run service.It works fine independently. I want to use a load balancer infront of cloud run . So i created a gloabl https load balancer with google manged certificate. Now my config is like
https Lb->https backend neg->cloudrun. My domain is from godaddy. so I updated my godaddy's "A" record with host entry for example "sample" to load balancer ip. Now when I hit my https url am getting the following error
**ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH**
Please help

Comment: 1) Have you waiting long enough for the load balancer SSL certificate to issue? 2) Your question lacks specific details on how you have configured each service. 3) Use tools such as the CLI `curl`. Post the output from `curl -v example.com` in your question. When you have domain or certificate issues, include the actual domain name and settings in your post.

Comment: The issue was not waiting enough for certificate to be active. It took 24 hrs for the cert to become active and serve request sucessfully

Comment: The Cloud Run custom domain dashboard indicates that a certificate is still provisioning. Wait until that is complete before doing anything else.